# JQuery mouseenter causes div elements to move

Tags: jquery, css, hover, mouseenter

Problem: When using JQuery to swap out elements (images) inside DIV tags the DIV's move around vertically. When not actually swapping the images and just hovering mouse with a border color change the DIV's don't move. So I know it isn't tied to :hover CSS problems. Ultimately the images will swap out to include an embed video preview. I have simplified it by using the cute kitten images and they produce the same problem.

The CSS:

```
.placecard { 
  margin:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:0px;
  border: 1px solid #12142E;
  overflow:hidden;
}
@media (max-width: 1250px) {
  .placecard {
    max-width:23.64%;
    height:auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1110px) {
  .placecard {
    max-width:31.64%;
    height:auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .placecard {
    max-width:31.32%;
    height:auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .placecard {
    max-width:47.52%;
    height:auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 552px) {
  .placecard {
    max-width:46.5%;
    height:auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .placecard {
    max-width:44.5%;
    height:auto;
  }
}
```

The Javascript:

```
$(".placecard").mouseenter(function() {
$(this).find(".modelimg").attr("id","object_container");

    var model = $(this).attr("title");
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
console.log(model+":"+width+":"+height);

var container    = document.getElementById('object_container'),
    parent       = container.parentNode,
    newContainer = document.createElement('div'),

    i            = 0;
while( !!document.getElementById('object_container_' + i ) ) { i++; }

newContainer.id = 'object_container_' + i;
newContainer.className = 'npt-object-container';
newContainer.style.display = 'inline-block';

newContainer.innerHTML = "<img width="+width+" height="+height+" src=\"http://placekitten.com/300/200\" >"
parent.insertBefore(newContainer, container);
$(container).css("display","none");
console.log($(newContainer).height());

}).mouseleave(function() {
    $("#object_container_0").remove()
    $("#object_container").css("display","block");
    $(this).find(".modelimg").removeAttr("id");
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="placecard"  data-profile="" title="Cat1">

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" class="modelimg"  />                    
</div>

<div class="placecard"  data-profile="" title="Cat2">

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" class="modelimg"  />                    
</div>

<div class="placecard"  data-profile="" title="Cat3">

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" class="modelimg"  />                    
</div>

<div class="placecard"  data-profile="" title="Cat4">

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" class="modelimg"  />                    
</div>

<div class="placecard"  data-profile="" title="Cat5">

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" class="modelimg"  />                    
</div>

<div class="placecard"  data-profile="" title="Cat6">

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" class="modelimg"  />                    
</div>

<div class="placecard"  data-profile="" title="Cat7">

<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" class="modelimg"  />                    
</div>
```

And A handle JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5snwxy6v/

JSFiddel updated: http://jsfiddle.net/5snwxy6v/3/

Comment: I set a height attribute to "placecard" and that seemed to fix the issue. Problem is that the container of the image is getting larger when you swap out the image. Trying placing a background color and notice how when you swap the image the background color appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of hacky, but placing line-height:0; attribute on placecard solves the issue.

Comment: Can you comment on why this is considered hacky, and therefore, tacky? Thus far it is the solution that solved my problem and works with responsive CSS on the site.

Comment: Here's something that ought to answer your question:
http://www.kirupa.com/html5/removing_space_between_images_using_css.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
.placecard { 
    margin:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:0px;
    height:200px;/*added*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/5snwxy6v/1/)

Comment: This fixes it, but there is one problem. My window is responsive so the width of .placecard is being set by conditions. I will update my question.